# Map files not created with sourceMap being enabled

Tags: typescript

Just started learning `TypeScript` from an hour ago:)

I have enabled `sourceMap` in the `tsconfig` file and rebuilt my project.
But still I don't see a map file that can enable TS debugging in browser.

What else should I be doing to get this working?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAA5z.png)

[image]